# How to implement Week view in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, calendar, xamarin.android

The past few days I was looking for a way to implement a calendar into my app.

The purpose is to make some booking system where the user can see a week calendar with hours (like the week view in S Planner) on it.  The hours coloured red will be the reserved hours. And the non-coloured hours show the user it’s free. And when they click on it they can book that hour.

I’ve found the Alliance Calendar for Xamarin. But it says it only shows the current month. And what I need is to show a week view.

I also found this on github: https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View
This is exactly what I was looking for. But this is all java code…

Does anyone know how I can create a week view in **Xamarin Android**? Can someone provide me an example how to achieve this?

All the help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is possible to use a native Java library with Xamarin.Android - you can create bindings for C#, use the JNI to call Java, or rewrite the Java into C#. This document explains how bindings work and provides examples for how to achieve bindings: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/. I suspect C# bindings are the way to go for this example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @DylanS! I will take a look :)

Comment: @Season Is there any success to integrate library? I have also same requirement to have week view in xamarin application.

Comment: Hi @ChintanRathod, unfortunately I did not successfully integrate this labrary... for the moment I've a temporary listview instead of a week view calendar. I'm planning to do this later. I will inform you if i've succeeded :)

Comment: @Season Thanks for your reply & it will help me definitely :) I have a question as I am doing it first time. Is it possible to integrate such libraries (3rd party from Github for Android & iOS) in native xamarin? Because if such thing is not possible, i just escalate to management.

Comment: @ChintanRathod It is also my first time doing this. But I've not implemented it yet, that's why I've not succeeded yet. 
But I suppose it is possible by creating bindings for C# like Dylan said. :) I've to implement other functionality first. So if you can't wait you can try it first and keep me up-to-date :)

Comment: Did somebody implement this Weekview of java library into Xamarin.android ? I wanna know its difficulty level of implementation and performance issues  before starting. Thank you in advance.